# Flex - How to send the ID of the selected item of a Flex DropDownList to the server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, drop-down-menu

I am using FlashBuilder 4.5 for PHP. I have a simple MySQL table with the fields {tID, tName}.

I am able to populate a DropDownList in a Flex form as below. The DropDownList shows the name of the people without problem:

```
<s:Form defaultButton="{button}">
 <s:FormItem label="myList: ">
  <s:DropDownList id="dropDownList" creationComplete="dropDownList_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >
   <s:AsyncListView list="{getPeopleResult.lastResult}"/>
  </s:DropDownList>
 </s:FormItem>
 <s:Button id="button" label="Submit"click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Form>
```

In my button_clickHandler function, I want to obtain the ID of the selected item from the dropdownlist:

```
protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 person.tID=dropDownList.selectedItem as int;

 createpersonResult.token=personservice.createperson(person);
}
```

The above does not work. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you try: person.tID=dropDownList.selectedItem as String;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this or similar :

```
person.tID=dropDownList.selectedItem.tID as int;
```

The straight value of `dropDownList.selectedItem` is probably "[Object]" - Most likely a `person` object with the fields `tID` and `tName`.

This is my guess based off the code I can see so far...   :)

Answer (score 0):

You should always use parseInt() OR parseFloat() for conversion from Number to String. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Sweet! Now, that works. I am now able to send the right data to the server when I add a new person. Now, the problem is that the datagrid is not properly updated.

Comment: Since the question is different, I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744972/flex-datagrid-not-updated-properly

Comment: Datagrid now updates without problem! Your help is very much appreciated!